# FluxUsingWhen cannot be cast to Iterable error when using spring data rest with reactive repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I configured a `ReactiveSortingRepository` to see the reactive capabilities on spring data rest, in the past I've mostly used `PagingAndSortingRepository` to expose resources as REST endpoints so wanted to see how well reactive stuff works.

the entity/document

```
public class Post extends AuditableDocument implements Serializable {

    private String title;

    private String content;

}
```

`AuditableDocument` has common properties for all resources such as `@Version`, `@LastModifiedDate` etc.

and then the repository

```
public interface PostRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Post, String> {
}
```

When I access the `http://localhost:8080/posts` on browser I get this error

```
{
   "cause":null,
   "message":"class reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen cannot be cast to class java.lang.Iterable (reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Iterable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"
}
```

And the stack trace

```
2021-06-29 09:48:38.252 ERROR 32221 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : class reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen cannot be cast to class java.lang.Iterable (reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Iterable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen cannot be cast to class java.lang.Iterable (reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Iterable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAllReflectively(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAll(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAll(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:163) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:202) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

here's the dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have got a similar dependencies incompatibility.

Comment: Spring DATA REST works on webmvc only, so we either either write the endpoint using webflux and hateoas for reactive stack or stick to spring data rest sans webflux.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both **Spring Data Rest** and **Spring Data MongoDB Reactive**, as *Anadi Misra* mentioned in the comments **Spring Data Rest** is only for *servlet* stack whereas **Spring Data MongoDB Reactive**, as the name states, lies on the *reactive* stack.

The solution would depend on your application type, *Imperative* or *Reactive*. If you're going for *Reactive* you need to replace `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` with `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and manually configure REST endpoints and use **Spring HATEOAS** if required. Or if you are making an *Imperative* application, you neeed to replace `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive`
with `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` and your **Spring Data Rest** should work fine.